i18n route alias not prefix in nuxt 3
I use nuxt 3 and nuxt/18n I have two languages ar and en and the default is ar
When I create a fan page, another router is created with prefix /en
For example, I have a page test.vue:
<script setup lang="ts">

definePageMeta({
   name : 'test',
   alias : ["/testExtend"]
});


</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Test App</h1>
  </div>
</template>


Routes will be:

/test
/en/test

Add to that alias
But the problem is that the same route is repeated:

/test
/en/test
/testExtend
/testExtend

/en is not added in the English version

in nuxt.config.ts i use experimental :
  experimental : {
    scanPageMeta : true
  },

